# How to get Particular value from string in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

i have a report value [Organization].[Organization].&[SB]
my requirement is to get only SB

> i have tried this

`=Mid(Parameters!RecallOrg.Value, InStr(Parameters!RecallOrg.Value,"&[")+1, (InStr(Parameters!RecallOrg.Value, "]") - InStr(Parameters!RecallOrg.Value, "&[") - 1))`

but getting error.

I'm able to solve the above prob but i'm facing a new issue here:
I have a parameter value: "Europe DAMS Finland", i need to extract only the name after 'DAMS'. how can i achieve that

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```
=MID(Parameters!RecallOrg.Value,InStr(Parameters!RecallOrg.Value,"&[")+2,(InStrRev(Parameters!RecallOrg.Value,"]")-InStr(Parameters!RecallOrg.Value,"&[")-2))
```

Comment: I tried by passing the value  [Organization].[Organization].&[SB]  to a textbox parameter and tried the above expression in a textbox. and I got the result. Are you using the same string. After MID( give the position of starting of 'S', which is 33 in the above string (we are finding position of '&[' which is 31 + 2) then after comma give the number of characters you need after &[ and before ], to find the characters we are subtracting position of ']' which is 35 (you have to use **InstrRev** to find this position)  and position of '&[' which is 31 and then -2 to find the position of 'S'

Comment: In your previous expression you got error because you where trying to subtract position of '&[', that is 31 from 1st position of ']' which is 14 (when you used **InStr** to find position of ], it finds the 1st position of ']', you have to use **InstrRev**) , that gave a -ve result (-18) for the number of characters after &[. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

you can also use split and replace:

```
=replace(replace(split(Parameters!RecallOrg.Value, "&")(1),"[",""),"]","")
```

Comment: its the array element, split converts into a zero-based array, "&" is the separator, so element (1) is the right side. Is there  a "&" always? what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

As @Jayvee said, you can use 'split' to get the needed result.
You have to use .GetValue(1) with it. Please find the code below.

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(split(Parameters!RecallOrg.Value, "&").GetValue(1),"[",""),"]","")
```